# How to put some relations into a custom defined field in the HTTP response in Laravel 6?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I'm working with a Laravel 6.x project and I need to manipulate the response format. I need to put my prices relations results into a `prices` field in the returning JSON response.

I have a Product model with these relationships:

```php
public function sellingPrices() {
    return $this->morphToMany(SellingPrice::class, 'product_variantables');
}

public function supplyingPrices() {
    return $this->morphToMany(SupplyingPrice::class, 'product_variantables');
}

public function supplierListPrices() {
    return $this->morphToMany(SupplierListPrice::class, 'product_variantables');
}
```

And here is the current code from my controller:

```php
public function index() {
    return Product::with([
        'orderStatus',
        'files',
        'properties',
        'sellingPrices',
        'suppyingPrices',
        'supplierListPrices',
        ])->get();
}
```

Of course this gets back this result:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "My Product",
  "order_status": { ... },
  "files": [],
  "properties": [],
  "selling_prices": [],
  "supplying_prices": [],
  "supplier_list_prices": []
}
```

What is the best way to say Laravel I want to get back this result?

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "My Product",
  "order_status": { ... },
  "files": [],
  "properties": [],
  "prices": {
    "selling_prices": [],
    "supplying_prices": [],
    "supplier_list_prices": []
  }
}
```

How can I put some relations into a custom defined field in the HTTP response?

Comment: sounds like you want a transformer or a api resource perhaps

Comment: I don't know. I'm looking for a solution what's working easly with many fields and avoid code duplitaction as much as possible

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem with API Resources. It's easy and best way. So more information check [API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-resources#introduction)